# (Android) Read Public or Shared Spreadsheet, Google Docs

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I can create a file and give permissions with Driver API.

For Spreadsheet i use "Spreadsheet API".

The permission that i give is: "public for anyone - read only". The case is i can't read the Spreadsheet Cells. The only way that i can read is if i add "Publish to the Web" like say James Moore. Code example:

```
String urlString = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AsaDhyyXNaFSdDJ2VUxtVGVWN1Yza1loU1RPVVU3OFE/default/public/values";
URL url = new URL(urlString);
ListFeed feed = service.getFeed(url, ListFeed.class); // Then feed.getEntries()
```

But if thats the case, how i can read a shared file or how i can set "Publish to the Web" a file via Java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that for now is not possible. Maybe in a near future;

Spreadsheet API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Weeks ago Google put some lines that explain this:

*The private visibility can be replaced with the public visibility, which enables the feed to work without authorization for spreadsheets that have been "Published to the Web". The public visibility is supported on the worksheets, list, and cells feeds. The public visibility is useful for accessing the contents of a spreadsheet from the client context of a web page in JavaScript, for example.*

*Publishing a spreadsheet to the web can only be done from the Google Spreadsheets user interface. To start publishing a spreadsheet to the web, select File > Publish to the web from the Spreadsheets user interface, and then click the Start Publishing button.*

***Warning:** API requests using the public visiblity for feeds on spreadsheets that are not "Published to the Web" yield an HTTP 400 Bad Request response with the message The spreadsheet at this URL could not be found. Make sure that you have the right URL and that the owner of the spreadsheet hasn't deleted it.*

***Warning:** The public visibility does not work for spreadsheets that are made "Public on the web" from the "Visibility options" portion of the sharing dialog of a Google Spreadsheet. "Published to the web" and "Public on the web" are different ways to share a spreadsheet. We are aware that this is confusing, and will address it in a future version of the API. For now, we hope that this detailed warning prevents confusion.*

Answer (score 0):

First, Documents List API is depricated. Use Drive API instead. You can achieve the same goal by [Files.insert()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert).

Second, use [spreadsheets api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) to read spreadsheet. You can also use [Spreadsheet service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) of Google Apps Script. You don't have to publish to the web if you use either one of these two.

Comment: Thanks 4 answer. Im already using Drive API and Spreadsheet API like u recommend and other forums too. But i have the same problem, how i can read a shared file? if i check it manually this is shared but i cant fetch the data... give an error saying "File don't exist or the url not is correct" something like that. How i can share and read the files that i shared?